# Is is "the 80s AD" or "the AD 80s"?

Tags: dates

I edit papers on ancient history, and one issue that keeps coming up is whether to refer to "the AD 80s" (or 50s or 90s etc, referring to a decade in the first century AD) or "the 80s AD".

New Hart's Rules simply states (p. 191):

> AD [...] should be placed before the numerals, as in *AD 375* (not *375 AD*). However, when the date is spelled out it is normal to write *the third century AD* rather than *AD the third century*.

However, it has no guidance on decades.

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=AD+80s%2C80s+AD%2CAD+90s%2C90s+AD%2CAD+30s%2C30s+AD%2CAD+40s%2C40s+AD&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAD%2080s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C80s%20AD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAD%2090s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C90s%20AD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAD%2030s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C30s%20AD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAD%2040s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C40s%20AD%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CAD%2080s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C80s%20AD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAD%2090s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C90s%20AD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAD%2030s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C30s%20AD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAD%2040s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C40s%20AD%3B%2Cc0) seems to indicate a preference for writing AD before the decade, but when it comes to phrases such as "the early 80s AD [or AD 80s]" there is very little data, and [what there is](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=early+AD+90s%2Cearly+90s+AD&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cearly%2090s%20AD%3B%2Cc0) seems to lean toward writing AD *after* the decade.

House style dictates the use of AD and BC, so I can't solve it by using CE instead.

So to summarize, how should the following phrases be written (bearing in mind they both occur in the same document, so need to be consistent)?

- the 80s AD, *or* the AD 80s?
- the early 90s AD, *or* the early AD 90s?

Many thanks.

Comment: "From AD 80 to AD 89". Or "The 80's of the first century AD", just as you'd write "The 80's of the 20th century AD".

Comment: But I wouldn't write "The 80's of the 20th century"; I'd write "the '80s" (the hyphen indicating the omission of "19"), or, for clarity, "the 1980s" (or "the 1880s", "the 1580s" etc. In the case of the first century, it's just "the 80s".
"From AD 80 to AD 89" might work in some contexts, but not when the original is "around the 80s AD" (your example would be too precise for "around") or "from the 80s to the early 90s AD".

Comment: It seems common these days to write AD after dates, which probably explains why you see "80s AD" more than "AD 80s". I don't think either looks too awful, so if it's not in any style guide your option would be to pick one. Chicago Manual of Style recommends "the first century AD" not "the AD first century" but I can't see anything on decades https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Abbreviations/faq0092.html

Comment: Be not afraid of of pedants who insist that A.D. can only abbreviate Anno Domini ("in the year of the lord") and so must only precede a single year number. Latin being Latin, it can as easily stand for Annorum Domini, as in the first century A.D. (i.e., the first set of 100 "of  years of the lord").